# How do I set the page title in an ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

In an ASP.NET MVC view I have the following code:

```
<% Page.Title = ViewData.Model.MyPageTitle; %>
```

and when I step through it I see the Page.Title value changing to the title that I want but when you look at the page's title shown in the browser it has not been modified. It appears that this value is overwritten by something later on.

Any ideas how the page title should be set if you want to do it dynamically?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326628/asp-net-mvc-view-with-master-page-how-to-set-title/653151#653151).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - View with master page, how to set title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326628/asp-net-mvc-view-with-master-page-how-to-set-title)

Comment: What version of MVC?  Any reason you aren't using razor (not related at all, just curious)?  What does your Masterpage/layout look like? I've found that having `Title` as a property on the model can sometimes mess with this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend 2 options.

First would to set something up in your master page that did something like this.

```
<% Page.Title = ViewData["Title"] ?? "Default title"; %>
```

Or set up a content placeholder in the head/title section that you could implement in your views to set the title with HTML.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you make contentplaceholder of head area in master
then you can define title in every page that inherits that master...

cheers