# How to set the master page's html title from within a controller's action or view page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller's action and view page that uses a master page.

The master page has the html title section like:

```
<title>this is the page's title</html>
```

How can I access this section from within my controller's action (preferably) or my action's view page?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326628/asp-net-mvc-view-with-master-page-how-to-set-title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<title><%= Model.PageTitle %></html>

public class MasterModel
{
    public string PageTitle { set; get; }
}

public class MyViewModel : MasterModel
{
    /* ... */
}
```

You can set the base class PageTitle property in a controller action all you want.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction ()
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel ();
    model.PageTitle = "this is the page's title";

    return View (model);
}
```

Comment: How do I get the master page to use the MasterModel though?  You are refering Model in the master page?

Comment: Ok I just referenced the base model in the master, thanks ALLOT!

Comment: Yep, the master page would be strongly-typed to the base class (MasterModel), while the views would use the derived model classes.

Answer (score 1):

The way I typically handle setting the title of html pages is through the pages Title property.

In my view I have this...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Title="Hello World" ... %>
```

And in my master page I have this...

```
<title><%=Page.Title%></title>
```

If you want to have the controller set the page title you will probably have to send the title in through the view model.

Comment: but on dynamic pages, how can you just hard code 'hello world' into the title?

Answer (score 0):

Pop the title you want into ViewData from the Action method and then just render it to the page...

In action method

```
ViewData["PageTitle"] = "Page title for current action";
```

On master page

```
<!-- MVC 1.0 -->
<title><%=Html.Encode(ViewData["PageTitle"]) %></title>

<!-- MVC 2.0 -->
<title><%: ViewData["PageTitle"] %></title>
```

Comment: yeah the problem is I use strongly typed ViewData for each action.