# ASP.NET MVC - How To Design Dynamic H1/Title Scheme?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, master-pages, page-title

If i have an ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application with the following Views:

1. **Main.aspx**
2. **Page1.aspx**
3. **Page2.aspx**

And all Views inherit from a MasterView called **Site.master**,

I want to be able to have a *default* Title/H1 for the page, which can be overriden in the deriving Views.

E.g Main.aspx would have "MySite - xxx", Page1.aspx would have "MySite - Page 1", Page2.aspx would have "MySite - Page2".

And if i choose *not to set* the Title/H1 in a new derived view, the master Title/H1 would be displayed.

With WebForms, i would accomplish this in the following way:

1. Make the Title/H1 tags on the master **runat="server"**
2. **Expose protected properties** on the master code-behind
3. On **Page_Load** of the derived pages code-behind, set the property (**Master.Title = "Page 1"**).
4. On **Page_PreRender** of the master code-behind, set the Title/H1 tags to **"My Site - " + Title;**

How can we accomplish this with ASP.NET MVC?

I could do this in the master:

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
```

And then set it in the view:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    MySite - Page 1
</asp:Content>
```

But i wanted to be able to only specify "Page 1" in the View, and the title gets magically changed to "MySite - Page 1". Know what i mean? The "MySite - " part of the title needs to be the template for the title.

I'm probably missing something obvious here. :)

Comment: I'm interested in this too, because i wanted the same thing as was surprised to find that `<title>MySite<asp:content.... /></title>` did not work as i expected.

Comment: Didn't even think of that - thanks for saving me some effort (with no reward, by the sounds of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a quick search I found this:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/03/tipjar-title-tags-and-master-pages.aspx

explains why

```
<title>MySite<asp:content..../></title>
```

doesn't work

Comment: Interesting article, admittedly i don't think i really bothered to search at the time, wasn't that bothered, but i didn't know it worked like that.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I usually do it:

```
<title>MySite - <%: Page.Title ?? "Default title" %></title>
```

in your MasterPage.

Then, you can define the `Title` property on a content page like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"
         MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
         Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"
         Title="Page 1"
%>
```

---

**Edit:**

Well, you might want to see this SO question: [ASP.NET MVC - View with master page, how to set title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326628/asp-net-mvc-view-with-master-page-how-to-set-title).

Answer (score 0):

Is much easier as you are describing it.

Just add a content placeholder to your master page

```
<title>
    My Site - <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageTitle" runat="server" />
</title>
```

Then in your Content Page use it as

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageTitle" runat="server">
    My Page
</asp:Content>
```

This way will work but you have to use an HTML HEAD tag, not a server control. So simply remove `runat="server"` from your HEAD.